# Why the login_user function not logiging me in?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm new to flask and all that backend thing, so i decided to start with flask. I found Miguel Grinberg's tutorial most beginner-friendly, so I started to follow it. But when tried to login the user with `login_user` it still didn't logged me in. The usernmame and the password are correct. I have a page protected with `@login_required` and when I pass the credentials, I still see the "Please log in to" access this page" message. Also the `login_user` function returns `True` and that's really strange. After that I copy-pasted the route function from the tutorial and it still didn't worked. Can you, guys, say what I'm doing wrong?

> Here's the route functions:

```py
from app import app, db
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from app.forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from app.models import User
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username': 'Andy'},
            'body': 'The Avengers film was awesome!'
        }
    ]
    return render_template('index.html',title='Home',posts=posts)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_pwd(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user,remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data,email=form.email.data)
        user.set_pwd(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you\'re now a registered user!')
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

Don't pay attention to the `posts` list

> Here's the `User` model:

```py
from app import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from app import login


class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64),index=True,unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120),index=True,unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post',backref='author',lazy='dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_pwd(self,pwd):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(pwd,'pbkdf2:sha1:10',60)

    def check_pwd(self,pwd):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,pwd)
```

if I need to add something here for you to understand, write in the comments

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because, on login, the User must have the `is_active` attribute and its value should be `True`.

To force login, you can pass argument `force=True`, like this   `login_user(user,remember=form.remember_me.data, force=True)`.

Or, you can add the `is_active` attribute on your User's model `is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)`.

Or, you can inherit from class `flask_login.UserMixin`, which provides default implementations for all of the properties and methods expected from flask login. I recommend it this way.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin):
    ...
```

You can look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/cb426683c05c481e9c5c0f0f2ca534e7259b4334/flask_login/utils.py#L147-L149) or [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/cb426683c05c481e9c5c0f0f2ca534e7259b4334/flask_login/utils.py#L169-L170) to see how it works.